# Mongoengine - JSONify EmbeddedDocumentListField

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Is there an easy way to return `EmbeddedDocumentListField` as JSON array in Mongoengine and Flask?

I've tried already to `dump` with `bson.json_util`, but only array of keys without values was returned. I have no aditional changes in model like `to_json()` method etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I succeeded with:

```
from bson.json_util import loads, dumps

...

c = Course.objects.get_or_404(id=course_id)

json = loads(c.to_json())

return dumps(json['assignments'])
```

First query target Document, load it as JSON and dumps only assignments array of `EmbeddedDocumentListField`